# fopen problem when mounting ecryptfs filesystem

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, encryption

After an unrecoverable fsck problem the mount of my encrypted `/home/me` filesystem isn't possible any more. The visible effects are: a) logging in though most of the selectable GUI window managers fails and returns to the login screen, and b) logging in through the mwm window manager or through a console puts me in my `/home/me` **stub** directory, where the readme file instructs me to invoke `ecryptfs-mount-private`.

Invoking `ecryptfs-mount-private` leads to two messages: 1) *"Inserted auth tok with sig [...]"*, and 2) *"Device or mountpoint is not a directory"*.
If invoking the same command using sudo there are also two messages: 1) the same as above, and 2) *"fopen: No such file or directory"*.

The mountpoints and permissions of the respective directories all seem fine, though.
Any hints what could be wrong with the mount directories and why this error message is shown?